# Multiple countdown timers comparing a given time and current time?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

Really struggling with this part for some reason.

I'm creating a timer I can use to keep track of bids. I want to be able to compare two times and have the difference (in minutes and seconds) shown in the countdown column. It should be comparing the bid start time and the time right now.

Perhaps when it reaches bid start it could also change to show how long until bid ends. Eventually I want to add background changes once it's getting close to the time, and perhaps the ablility to set alarms with a prompt window.

Here's the code I have so far:

HTML

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td><input id="itemNameField" placeholder="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time of Notice</td>
        <td><input id="noticeField" type="time"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<input id="addButton" onclick="insRow()" type="button" value="Add Timer">
<div id="errorMessage"></div>
<hr>
<div id="marketTimerTableDiv">
    <table border="1" id="marketTimerTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>Time of Notice</td>
            <td>Bid Start</td>
            <td>Bid End</td>
            <td>Countdown</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div id="itembox"></div>Example Item
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="noticebox"></div>12:52
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="bidstartbox"></div>13:02
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="bidendbox"></div>13:07
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="countdownbox"></div>
            </td>
            <td><input id="delbutton" onclick="deleteRow(this)" type="button" value="X"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function deleteRow(row) {
var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
if (i == 1) {
    console.log = "hi";
} else {
    document.getElementById('marketTimerTable').deleteRow(i);
}
}

function insRow() {
    if (itemNameField.value == "" || noticeField.value == "") {
        var div = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
        div.innerHTML = "*Please fill in the fields*";
        div.style.color = 'red';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    } else {
        var div = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
        div.innerHTML = "";
        var x = document.getElementById('marketTimerTable');
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
        var len = x.rows.length;
        var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        inp1.id += len;
        inp1.innerHTML = itemNameField.value;
        itemNameField.value = "";
        var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        inp2.id += len;
        inp2.innerHTML = noticeField.value;
        noticeField.stepUp(10);
        var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        inp3.id += len;
        inp3.innerHTML = noticeField.value;
        noticeField.stepUp(5);
        var inp4 = new_row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        inp4.id += len;
        inp4.innerHTML = noticeField.value;
        var inp5 = new_row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        inp5.id += len;
        inp5.innerHTML = "";
        noticeField.value = "";
        x.appendChild(new_row);
    }
}
```

I apologize in advance because my code is probably really messy and badly formatted. Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6fqpxce3/) as well! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference between the current and given time, you can use `setInterval`

Example :

```
var noticeTime = noticeField.value.split(":");
    const interval = setInterval(function(){
      var currentDate = (new Date());
      var diffInHours = currentDate.getHours() - noticeTime[0];
      var diffInMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes() - noticeTime[1];
      inp5.innerHTML = diffInHours + ":" + diffInMinutes;
      if(diffInHours === 0 && diffInMinutes === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    },1000)
```

Comment: I've tried using this but it just seems very messy and awkward to get it to do what I want it to because of the "noticeField.value.split".... I feel like it would be better to convert the noticeField time into seconds and then work out the difference from there. Struggling to get my head around it though

Comment: As there is only a `Date` object we can use to get the difference in milliseconds, we would need to convert the hours and minutes into milliseconds. This would require more effort and calculations from our part, that's why suggested the above solution. Let me know if you find any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: I've tried this instead but the calculations are just going completely wrong and I can't work out why. So confused..

       `var noticeTimeMinutes = (noticeTime[0] * 60) + noticeTime[1] + 5;

      var currentTimeMinutes = (currentDate.getHours() * 60) + currentDate.getMinutes();

      var diffTotalMinutes = (noticeTimeMinutes - currentTimeMinutes);`

Comment: You have modified your `noticeField` values by doing the `noticeField.step()` function. So if you need the original time, you should store it first in different value.

Comment: Hm I don't think that's what the problem is.. The stepUp only adds 15 minutes from the time of notice and I need the bid start time anyway which is why I've added 5 minutes onto the time to counteract the stepUp. I've even taken the stepUp out completely and still having the problem. The value I'm getting though is over 500000 minutes when it's only actually 10 minutes away. Not sure how though..

Comment: Ok I finally understood it.... I was getting weird numbers because it was still splitting them. So it was basically doing 30:540 + 10:540 would equal 40:1080 instead of adding it all up to 1120..Not sure what I can do to get around this :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the help of the code from ProgXx.

I added the following code:

```
var noticeTime = noticeField.value.split(":");
var originalTime = noticeField.value.split(":");
const interval = setInterval(function(){
  var currentDate = (new Date());
  noticeTime[1] = originalTime[1] - currentDate.getMinutes() + 10;
  noticeTime[1] = noticeTime[1] + (originalTime[0] * 60) - (currentDate.getHours() * 60);
```

Here's a JSFIDDLE of the finihsed code: http://jsfiddle.net/joefj8wb/